# Follow-up intents in Api.ai are not working on actions on google simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In API.ai, I have created follow-up intents for `yes` or `no` answers. They work fine in Web simulator and API.ai but not working on actions.google simulator. When the user says `yes` or `no`, the response from the simulator is "Sorry, this action is not available in the simulation".

Does anyone have an answer for this?

Here are the screenshots.

[tip-teller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhYGs.jpg)
[tip-teller-yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWtj.jpg)

Comment: Follow up intents in API.AI use contexts to control how the follow up intents are matched. Did first match the parent intent and then say "yes" or "no"?

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of the intents and sample conversations to illustrate what is happening? It is difficult to diagnose the problem without further information.

Comment: I have added two images. It works pefectly in API.AI simulation. But on actions.google , it doesn't trigger `tip-teller-yes` intent when I say `ok` to Device permissions dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

Hirikiran,

I think your input context on "tip-teller-yes" intent might be only one input context from main intent (tip-teller) which mean that it will be only "tip-teller-followup" input context.

Moreover, an important thing to note is you should manually add "User says" such as yes, sure, yep, yeah, that's right, etc or use Dialogflow yes-no follow-up template.

I think this might help, Dialogflow Documents https://dialogflow.com/docs/examples/slot-filling.